# validation using real named scopes rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an invoice model with approver_note, po_number and state_type.

I need validations to check:

```
scope :approver, where(state_type: 3)
scope :po_no, where(state_type: 2)

validates :approver_note, :presence => true, uniqueness: { scope: [:ac_id, :approver]}, if: :state_three?
validates :po_number, :presence => true, uniqueness: { scope: [:ac_id, :po_no]}, if: :state_two?

def state_three?
    self.state_type==3
end

def state_two?
    self.state_type==2
end
```

How can I make sure that the uniqueness in approver_note validator is run on selected scope of records. It should validate using records having state_type=3.

I need something in the similar lines of this bug...

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4325-real-scope-support-for-activerecords-uniqueness-validation

Is this available in rails now? or can we achieve this using custom validation?

Comment: Why not to check it with Rspec?

Comment: @MaximPontyushenko Can you please elaborate? I didn't get you...Sorry about that.

Comment: did you try out the custom validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scope` option of `uniquness` checks if the combination of 2 column values is uniq in the table, frankly I really I don't see how it would be clever enough to apply a dynamic scope. Too much magic even for rails !

However a custom validator is quite straightforward :

```
validate :approver_note_scoped_uniqueness, if: :state_three?

def approver_note_scoped_uniqueness
  if self.class.approver.where(ac_id: ac_id).count > 0
    errors.add(:ac_id, "My custom error message")
  end
end
```

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Adding to that, I see that the conditions option is available in validate_uniqueness_of from Rails 4. We can use that and construct two validations one for presence and one for uniqueness. Just in case if some one is looking for an answer in Rails 4.

In case of Rails 4,

```
validates_presence_of :approver_note, if: :state_three?
validates_presence_of :po_number, if: :state_two?
validates_uniqueness_of :approver_note, scope: [:ac_id], conditions: -> { where(state_type: 3)}, if: :state_three?
validates_uniqueness_of :po_number, scope: [:ac_id], conditions: -> { where(state_type: 2)}, if: :state_two?

def state_three?
    self.state_type==3
end

def state_two?
    self.state_type==2
end
```